# Como escrever uma agenda em ordem alfabética de Nomes, se a estrutura dicionário não tem ordem?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escreva um programa que receba quantas entradas o usuário desejar e depois
crie um novo contato para cada entrada (Nome, Telefone, Endereço, Email), e
por fim imprima, em ordem alfabética, a agenda de contatos :

```
Nomes = []
Telefones = []
Endereços = []
Emails = []
Agenda = {"Nome": Nomes,"Telefone":Telefones,"Endereço":Endereços, "Email": Emails}
entrada = ""
while entrada != "s":
    print("Bem-vindo a nossa Agenda!!!!!")
    nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
    Nomes.append(nome)
    telefone = input("Digite o telefone: ")
    Telefones.append(telefone)
    endereço = input("Digite o endereço: ")
    Endereços.append(endereço)
    email = input("Digite o email: ")
    Emails.append(email)
    print(Agenda)
    entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        print(Agenda)
        break
```

A agenda é um dicionário e ele não tem ordenação! Como posso imprimir a agenda em ordem alfabética de nomes, seguida das repectivas outras informações (Telefone, Endereço, Email) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nomes = []
telefones = []
endereços = []
emails = []

Agenda = {"Nome": nomes,
          "Telefone": telefones,
          "Endereço": endereços,
          "Email": emails
          }

entrada = ""
while entrada.lower() != "s":
    print("Bem-vindo a nossa Agenda!!!!!")

nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
nomes.append(nome)

telefone = input("Digite o telefone: ")
telefones.append(telefone)

endereço = input("Digite o endereço: ")
endereços.append(endereço)

email = input("Digite o email: ")
emails.append(email)

entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
if entrada.lower() == "s":

    ordenada = sorted(Agenda['Nome'])

    for nome in ordenada:
        i = Nomes.index(nome)
        for chave, valor in Agenda.items():
            if chave == 'Email':
                print('{}: {}.\n'.format(chave, valor[i]))
            else:
                print('{}: {}.'.format(chave, valor[i].title()))
```

Comment: O que faz o zip? Não entendi

Comment: A agenda não está em ordem alfabética de nomes!

Comment: O zip serve para agregar os elementos de um iterador. Nesse caso ele pega uma posição das suas listas, por exemplo, a posição 0,  e  os reúne numa lista de tuplas, onde cada tupla é um contato. O laço for percorre cada tupla e exibe seu conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

```
Nomes = []
Telefones = []
Endereços = []
Emails = []
Agenda = {"Nome": Nomes,"Telefone":Telefones,"Endereço":Endereços,
          "Email": Emails}
entrada = ""

print("Bem-vindo a nossa Agenda!!!!!")
while entrada != "s":

    nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
    Nomes.append(nome)
    telefone = input("Digite o telefone: ")
    Telefones.append(telefone)
    endereço = input("Digite o endereço: ")
    Endereços.append(endereço)
    email = input("Digite o email: ")
    Emails.append(email)
    #print(Agenda)
    entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
    print()
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        ordenada = sorted(Agenda['Nome']) 
        for nome in ordenada:  
            print()
            print("Nome: ",Agenda['Nome'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Telefone: ",Agenda['Telefone'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Endereço: ",Agenda['Endereço'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Email: ",Agenda['Email'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print()
        break
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Nomes = []
Telefones = []
Endereços = []
Emails = []
Agenda = [] # Agenda Agora é uma lista que recebe dicionários
entrada = ""
count = 0 #Contador

# Condição para funcionamento
while True:
    print("Bem-vindo a nossa Agenda!!!!!")
    nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
    telefone = input("Digite o telefone: ")
    endereço = input("Digite o endereço: ")
    email = input("Digite o email: ")

    # Lista 
    Agenda.append({"Nome": nome,"Telefone":telefone,"Endereço":endereço, "Email": email})

    # Contador conta quantos contatos foram adicionados na agenda
    count+= 1
    print(f'Foram adicionados {count} itens na Agenda!')

    # Verifica se quer sair
    entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
    if entrada.lower() in ('s', 'y'): # Você pode digitar sim, s, Sim, sim, y, Yes, etc
        break

# Ordena a lista Agenda por Nomes
Agenda.sort(key=lambda Agenda: Agenda["Nome"])
for i in Agenda:
    print(i)
```